# Assert downloading Pytorch models (model.pth does not exist)

Tags: pytorch

I am having this problem trying to use [LayoutParser](https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser) but I believe it is actually an issue with Pytorch checkpoint.  [I get the following assert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlBHl.png)

The directory contains model.pth?dl=1 and model.pth.lock

It looks like the downloading creates a file called model.pth?dl=1 and and a .lock file.  But it fails to finish by renaming it to model.pth.  It seems to happen with all LayoutParser pretrained models.

Anyone seen this?

Thank you
Peter

The assert is thrown from this call with any of the pretrained models

The full code to reproduce this is:

```
import layoutparser as lp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel(
        config_path="lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config",
        label_map={0:"Text",1:"Title",2:"List",3:"Table",4:"Figure"},
        extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST",0.1]
)
```

Comment: Additional info: the bug does not occur on my Mac laptop.  It seems to be a problem with Linux

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The  full code to reproduce this error is: